# How can I make installment payments on Opencart

Tags: content-management-system, opencart

So the question is how you can implement the button "Buy credit"? Do you have modules or do you need a layout?))

Comment: i have a module ? it's working superb. you can see https://www.getonthewater.co.uk/surflogic-wetsuit-pro-dryer

Comment: which actual version of opencart you have ?

Answer (score 0):

Installment option provided by payment processing companies . Not with our Open Cart .